# Crop tool not working as expected in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, crop

I selected Crop tool and selected the area to crop but it is actually hiding the remaining area. After selecting i clicked delete radio button but that also not working as expected.

I need to crop a part of the shape, my shape is a rounded rectangle..I need to get a rectangle whose two corners are rounded where other two will be square. So i thought of cropping from half rounded rectangle.

Is there any other way to crop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is another way to crop. Create a marquee with any of the tools available for doing so (marquee, pen to selection, select layer, etc...) then do Image -> Crop.

**Edit**

There's a bunch of ways to achieve what you're really looking for (*based on comment*). The first is by **Cutting**.

1. Draw rounded rectangle
2. Select just in from the curved corner
3. Delete Button on keyboard. If it says you can't then you need to *rasterize* the layer. Right click on it on your layer palette and select rasterize.

You can also use the **Pen Tool** to for better results but doesn't really do any sort of deleting which is why I'm putting this second.

1. Choose the vector rounded rectangle (No Rasterize)
2. Choose the Convert Point Tool on your main toolbar, its in the Pen submenu
3. Convert all the points on the side you want straight
4. Choose the Delete Anchor Point Tool on the same menu
5. Click on the two outer most points

Comment: Thats what i forgot, i need to rasterize the layer, Thanks